# python merging two dictionaries without deleting any keys

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

#two dicts
`a = { "a": { "b": "bbb", "c": "ccc" }} b = { "a": { "b": "aaa" }}`

#update
`a.update(b)`

#result:
`{'a': {'b': 'aaa'}}`

#what I do want
`{'a': {'b': 'aaa', 'c': 'ccc'}}`

#don't want the "c" key to be deleted/removed

the update method doesnt seem to have any args to not delete.
Is there a built-in python method to do this
or do you need to write your own custom update to not remove keys but to still be able to overwrite values??

Comment: The update method will replace the values if the key is the same. In your case { "b": "bbb", "c": "ccc" } is the value of key "a" and hence when you use the update method it gets updated with the new value from the dict b i.e { "b": "aaa" }.

Comment: It is *crucial* to understand: **no keys were removed in the dictionary that was updated**

Comment: regarding the **no keys were removed in the dictionary that was updated**
I'm not understanding it.  a is the dict with "c" key, once the update was run, the c key is no longer there?  how is it not being removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the dictionary inside `a` where the key is `"a"`.

```
a = { "a": { "b": "bbb", "c": "ccc" }}
b = { "a": { "b": "aaa" }}

for k, v in b.items():
    if k in a:
        a[k].update(b[k])
    else:
        a[k] = v
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom update function for your operation.

```
def custom_update(target, source):
    for key, value in source.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict) and key in target and isinstance(target[key], dict):
            custom_update(target[key], value)
        else:
            target[key] = value

custom_update(a, b)
```

Comment: Do you know you can mention the types of arguments and return type in Python?

Comment: In above function, target and source in argument is dictionary, and it returns nothing because it accesses and modifies values directly. The function would look better if i mention the types of arguments and return types!

Comment: Your code breaks. Doesn't work.